# In VC++ Notification Callbacks Can NMHDR* be NULL?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

Below is some sample code taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistctrl-class?view=vs-2019. In all examples I have seen it is not checking if NMHDR* is null or not. Can it be null or is it guaranteed not to be null?

```
void CListCtrlDlg::OnDblClk(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pResult);
    LPNMITEMACTIVATE pia = (LPNMITEMACTIVATE)pNMHDR;
    LVHITTESTINFO lvhti;

    // Clear the subitem text the user clicked on.
    lvhti.pt = pia->ptAction;
    m_myListCtrl.SubItemHitTest(&lvhti);

    if (lvhti.flags & LVHT_ONITEMLABEL)
    {
        m_myListCtrl.SetItemText(lvhti.iItem, lvhti.iSubItem, NULL);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it can't be? I'm not sure it'd make sense for it to ever be null. But it's very little overhead to explicitly test it, and you can always install the MFC source and check the code that calls it to see if that can ever generate a null.

Answer (score 1):

If a handler such as the `CListCtrlDlg::OnDblClk` function you have shown is called ***by the MFC Framework***, in response to the relevant `WM_NOTIFY` message, then the `NMHDR*` parameter will *not* be `NULL`.

However, it is *possible* to call such a handler function manually, in which case that parameter can have any value the calling code(r) cares to give it.

So, in terms long-term safety and/or maintenance - *especially when working with codebases accessed and/or modified by other programmers, over whom you have little or no control* - you may wish to check the validity of the pointer.

Comment: Incidentally, *"for better long-term safety"* I'd opt for the opposite: Don't check for a `nullptr`. Just act on the valid assumption, that this argument cannot ever be a `nullptr`, and unconditionally dereference it. If someone implements changes that do the wrong thing (like calling a notification handler directly), have your program **instantly** crash. This has two benefits: The editor gets immediate feedback, and the feedback is of the kind they cannot (accidentally) ignore.

Comment: @IInspectable I can't and won't dispute your philosophy. At all. I'm just saying it is *possible* to get a `nullptr` first argument; that could even be implemented as a feature, where the 'other programmer' has added the relevant check for that `nullptr` and handles it accordingly. For example, a button-click emulating a double-click in another control.

Comment: *"Emulating a double-click"* is questionable already. Either inject a genuine double-click (using `SendInput`), or trigger the effect of a double-click (using UI Automation or similar patterns). This isn't just philosophy either: It's what I've used and introduced into many MFC code bases. Even at those times, where it was initially met with resentment, it turned out to be successful in rejecting quick-and-dirty hacks (aka technical debt) as well as providing full fidelity for each and every sound use case.

Comment: @IInspectable Again, no dispute in terms of the questionability of the 'example usage' I gave in my last comment. Also, I have edited my answer so that it leans less towards suggesting that overriding the Framework is in any way acceptable. As ever, I appreciate your insightful comments.